# Aurelia compose with globalResources

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

Our plan is the following: A dashboard with webparts. We plan on develop many different "webparts" (as custom elements), and later, based on role or preferences we will show just a selection of the availible webparts.

Say I have the following custom elements in a dashboard.

```
<template>
   <my-webpart1 state.bind="state"></my-webpart1>
   <my-webpart2 state.bind="state"></my-webpart2>
   <my-webpart3 state.bind="state"></my-webpart3>
   <my-webpart4 state.bind="state"></my-webpart4>
   <my-webpart5 state.bind="state"></my-webpart5>
</template>
```

Is it possible to iterate over the names instead?

```
<div repeat.for="webpartname of manager.webparts">
  <compose view-model="${webpartname}" ></compose>
</div>
```

First problem is that the webparts are developed in different features and is registered using `.globalResources()` - how can I get the url?

Then the second problem is how to do the binding. I've not started on that yet.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Regards

Larsi

Comment: Maybe it would be better to simply use `if.bind` or `show.bind` attributes on each part instead of using `compose`.

Comment: @JeffG agree. I ended up doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if.bind` or `show.bind` attributes on each part instead of using `compose`.

Comment: Please mark this as correct since this is the way you decided to go. Thanks!